# configured as a single instance, but instantiated twice

Tags: spring

spring.version=5.2.7.RELEASE

```
public class Service15 {
   public Service15(){
    System.out.println("service15 init");
  }
}
```

```
public class Service15Factory implements FactoryBean, BeanFactoryAware {
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    public Service15Factory(){
        System.out.println("serviceFactory15 init");
    }
    @Override
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        beanFactory.getBean("service16");
        return new Service15();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Service15.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

```
public class Service16 {
    private Service15 service15;
    public Service16(){
        System.out.println("service16 init");
    }
    public void setService15(Service15 service15){
        this.service15 = service15;
    }
}
```

configuration：

```xml
<bean id="service15" class="com.myspring.service.Service15Factory" scope="singleton">
</bean>
<bean id="service16" class="com.myspring.service.Service16">
    <property name="service15" ref="service15"></property>
</bean>
```

I created three classes,service15 will be created by getObject of `Service15Factory`, and `Service16` dependent on service15,service15 will be Initialized twice

Comment: `return new Service15();`. Answer your question?

Comment: Your code leads to eagerly init of service due to the bean lookup. Also is this really everything? Could be that something creates a (class) proxy leading to another instance.